# How can I enable std::experimental::atomic_shared_pointer

Tags: c++, include

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. And I have gcc-9.2.0, but I cant find the atomic header file in `/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/experimental`, I guess I might have to enable it when I compile gcc or I have to install it manually, but I didnt find any clue about how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

So my understanding `std::experimental::atomic_shared_pointer` is for now [std::atomic(std::shared_ptr)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2), so I don't think there is (and maybe won't) be any way to enable `std::experimental::atomic_shared_pointer`.

And that's how I also would interpret this
[en.cppreference.com: std::experimental::atomic_shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/atomic_shared_ptr):

> Merged into ISO C++ The functionality described on this page was merged into the mainline ISO C++ standard as of 11/2017; see std::atomic> (since C++20)

Comment: But I didnt find this template specialization in my `/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/atomic` as well, so where is this template specialization located???